# Does Internet Explorer support arguments.callee.name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, mootools

I know I can get the name of the current running function by using

```
arguments.callee.caller.name
```

**But this does not work in Internet Explorer** (any version). What's the correct cross-browser syntax? Does a workaround exist?

Comment: You can't do this anymore. It's deprecated. Relying on this is bad code. Refactor it away

Comment: Even if I regret it, Raynos is right. `arguments.callee` and `.caller` are both deprecated. The ECMA commitee figured those references created more harm than good. Any browser which supports `strict mode` will throw an exception when using those propertys aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that `arguments.callee` is effectively being phased out and is completely absent in ECMAScript 5 strict mode, the main issue is that `Function` objects in IE do not have the `name` property. It is implemented in some browsers, notably Firefox and recent WebKit-based browsers, but is non-standard, and indeed there is no standardized way to get hold of a function name.

The only option this leaves you is trying to parse the name from the function's string representation, which is **not a good idea**. There's a (long) discussion here about it: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/browse_frm/thread/b85dfb2f2006c9f0.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

arguments.callee.caller.$name

as in IE it supports with $name