# Variables not defined in IE11 but defined in Chrome

Tags: javascript, variables

There is a namepicker which is not functioning properly in IE11 but works fine in Chrome.

On inspection I found that the variables are undefined in IE11 but are defined in Chrome.

I used the alert function in the function to test the variable.

The very 1st time I load the page, the variables are defined. On a refresh the variables becomes unset. This function is called by onLoad in HTML document

```
function fillInitialValues() {
    alert("Inside fillinitialvalues ");
    alert("caller is " + arguments.callee.caller.toString());

    if (typeof isSingle !== 'undefined') {
        // the variable is defined
        alert("Variable isSingle is defined" + isSingle);
    } else {
        alert("Variable isSingle is not defined");
    }

    if (!isSingle) {
        alert("Inside fillinitialvalues checking in issingle");
        targetNames = trimArray(baseTargetNames);
        alert("base target names contain " + targetNames);
        output = generateNamesHTML(targetNames, 'T');
        writeDiv('target', output);
    }

    self.focus();
    document.getElementById('searchcriteria').focus();
}
```

Comment: Where is `isSingle ` defined? What scope does it exist in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735931/does-internet-explorer-support-arguments-callee-name  tl;dr: don't use `arguments.callee`